# Vue.js and Moment.js: Condition for deleting a comment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, momentjs, directive

I need to be able to delete a comment when two conditions are observed:

1. `Id` of a comment's author is equal to our id (we can delete only our comments).
2. It had been less than 15 minutes since the moment of comment creating.

I made the first condition but I am struggling to do and add the second one using Moment.js. Every comment has a `created_at` property.

```
<a v-if="comment.author.id == myProfile.id"
   v-on:click.stop="deletePostComment({ params: { post_id: getPost.id, comment_id: comment.id } })"
   class="g-color-gray-light-v1 g-color-gray-dark-v3--hover g-font-size-12 float-right u-link-v5 magic-absolute-position"
   style="cursor: pointer;">
                Delete
</a>
```

I suppose that we can have this two conditions in one function. Please help!

Comment: In what format is the `created_at` timestamp?

Comment: When I display this time in other components, I do it like this:
`return moment(this.item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').fromNow();`

Comment: The format is like this: `created_at:"2018-02-07 11:40:00 +0000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do add `v-if` directive with a function `showDelete`, which would show or hide the option "Delete" for a comment depending on those two conditions.

Then I put this function in `computed`:

```
showDelete() {
  return moment().diff(moment(this.comment.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'), 'minutes') <= 15 && this.comment.author.id === this.myProfile.id;
}
```

So this function will listen to boolean values. If `true`, than it will show the option "Delete".

Answer (score 0):

You can check if 15 minutes has passed by substracting the current date from the `created_at` date:

```
var now = new Date();
var created_at = new Date('2/9/2018 12:05')
```

and then compare it with the 15 minutes value. Something like below should work:

```
<a v-if="comment.author.id == myProfile.id && created_at - now >= 15*60*1000"
   v-on:click.stop="deletePostComment({ params: { post_id: getPost.id, comment_id: comment.id } })"
   class="g-color-gray-light-v1 g-color-gray-dark-v3--hover g-font-size-12 float-right u-link-v5 magic-absolute-position"
   style="cursor: pointer;">
                Delete
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what is `15*60*1000` here.

Comment: This is how we calculate minutes in unix format. The 15 minutes value you actually need to compare.

Answer (score 0):

**What about this?:**

```
<div v-if="isPastime('2018-02-07 11:40:00 +0000', 15, 'days')"></div>
<!-- In you case so do something like -->
<a v-if="comment.author.id === myProfile.id && isPastime(comment.created_at, 15, 'days')"></a>
```

**Method:**

```
methods: {
    isPastime: function (time, number, unit) {
        return moment(time).diff(moment(), unit) <= - number
    }
}
```